# JavaFX Intellij error "Error:java: invalid flag: --add-modules=javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.controls,javafx.base"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, compiler-errors

The error itself:

> Error:java: invalid flag: --add-modules=javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.controls,javafx.base

This error occurs when [this](https://github.com/TeamSteamRobotics/LearningSimulatorGUI) javafx application is ran. I am running this project from a newly setup laptop and am not sure what i'm doing to cause this error, it works just fine on my desktop. I'm using intellij Community 2018.2 and JKD 10 on both my desktop and laptop.

Searching this error does not yield much information (to me) and i'm not really sure where to even start. I'm not using any fxml either if that makes a difference. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Could you check the Project SDK being used for the project in IntelliJ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha The project SDK for the desktop version was for some reason selected to "<No SDK>. Switching this to SDK 10, then pushing to git fixed the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ItachiUchiha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1759128/itachiuchiha) for leading me to the answer.

Checking the SDK for my pc revealed that there was no SDK selected. I'm not sure how it was working before.

[image: No SDK]

Switching this to SDK 10, the same SDK my laptop uses, then pushing the changes to git, then pulling from git on the laptop, solved the error.

[image: SDK10]

Answer (score 8):

You need to remove it from the compilation options. Go to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler. In Javac Options you will see entries for the compilcation options for each projects. Remove it from there.